# Need an output variable

Tags: sql

I have been creating a few stored procedures to use with a database. The procedures would take in a variable and conduct the search and return pertaining results. What I am having an issue with, however, is that I would like there to print a message whenever the procedure returns no information. I understand I would use an if statement and print command for this. However, how would I reference the output?

Is there a way to write 'IF output = null, print message'?

Comment: Is a full message required to be generated from the sproc? Could you do with generating it in the calling code, triggered when the output table is empty?

Comment: The print part is simply just a message in the message window saying the input wasn't valid.

Comment: So your procedure will return _either_ a result set _or_ a message if there are no results?  That will make calling the procedure more complicated.  Why return a message?  Does it give the caller more information about _why_ there is no data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could
create a table valued variable and then populate it with the data you selected.